# Are there any large projects which use Python 2/3 compatible source as a porting strategy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As we all know, there are several strategies for porting to and support Python 2 and 3 at the same time: it's possible to write directly in Python 3 and then use 3to2, you can write in Python 2 and use 2to3 at install time, or you can write code that is compatible with Python 2 and Python 3 at the same time. Now, in my experience, most projects use the second strategy, with running 2to3 at install time. I also feel that this is a superior approach, however it's been suggested to me that writing 2/3 compatible source might be a better idea for a project I want to work on. As such, I'm wondering, **are there any major projects with 2/3 compatible source?** The only larger project I'm aware of is [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/).

Alternatively, are there any sources (eg. attempts to port) to show that this is a bad idea? I feel that for any moderately sized code-base, this means relying too much on Python internals and would ultimately slow down development. Obviously, it can work fine for smaller projects (eg. up to 10k lines of code).

Comment: Poll / list questions are considered off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-July/051436.html for the announcement of Python 3 support in NumPy.

Comment: @VPeric I suggest you rephrase your question to focus on the technical reasons of using 2/3 compatible source vs using 3to2 and hope a more experienced person can explain when its the appropriate case to use either

Answer (score 0):

I believe that pyramid runs on both 2 and 3 with the same code base as suggested here.

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/wiki/Python-3-Porting